# Opposite of “turnaround”

Tags: antonyms

The dictionary says that a “turnaround” is “an abrupt or unexpected change, esp. one that results in a more favorable situation”. What would be the word for “an abrupt or unexpected change” which is NOT favourable and worsens the situation?

Comment: "weekday"... :-(

Comment: @Oddthinking: ohh, so true indeed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word could be *reversal*. Here are links to [OED Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_gb0707270#m_en_gb0707270) and [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reversal).

> Many Internet firms have suffered a painful reversal of fortune.

Comment: Could go either way with a modifier - "The team saw a miraculous reversal at the end of the season saving them from relegation"

Comment: Yes, thank you, it sounds like the best option for what I’ve got.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think of a *word* but two good expressions would be:

> - take a turn for the worse
> - take a nosedive

Comment: I vote for "nosedive."

Comment: nosedive++ ....

Answer (score 0):

Don't hold me to this but 'upset' as a verb can mean overtun and to become overturned.
Because of the way we use it day to day. I feel like it's taken on a *mainly* pejorative sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling it "a disaster."

Answer (score 0):

"Turnarounds" are rarely unexpected, in the context of economics, or the fortunes of people or individual companies. More often, it has the sense of "self-rescue".

I like Jimi Oke's "take a turn for the worse".

Answer (score 0):

For an unexpected change of fortune, I can think of an optimistic word...

Because colloquially we plan for our plans to succeed one can usually use the optimistic term **setback** [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/setback).
Example: "The injury of their star player was a significant *setback* for the team."